# Converting numerical date back to date in Python

Tags: python, datetime, linear-regression, datetime-format

I created a dataframe with the first column as 'date', the rest our numerical columns.

```
date    transportation  pm25    pm10    ozone   no2 so2 co  final_aqi   label
719163       21         162     193     24      40   2   16    193     119.0
....
589 rows × 10 columns
```

Here I converted the dates to numeric form using

```
import datetime as dt

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
```

I wish to use linear regression on my code, will my predictions be altered if my date is numeric(date column is a feature)? Also how should I go back to the date format?

Answer (score 0):

If date is not one of the input features, then there is no effect at all because it will not be included in your features matrix.
If date is an input to your model. i.e. one of the input features, then keep it numerical as it's.
If your model is predicting something that is related to a specific date, then it's better to include the distance from that date. i.e. (date - specific date)